# loop is not running for Cursor in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written a query where I'm selecting 2 columns and these are around 40 records.

Now I want to do sum calculation on these records by selecting one by one.

In my stored procedure, I have taken a cursor where m storing those 40 records. And using a for loop and doing the sum calculation on these records (one by one)

But for the first record, sum is coming empty and my loop is not taking another record from the cursor.

And that's why I am not able to calculate sum for each record one by one because my for loop is not running again.

```
    cursor details is
        select distinct lpn_id v_olpn_id, lpn_detail_id v_olpn_detail_id
        from   lpn_detail ld
        where  size_value > '0'
        and    lpn_id in
               ( select lpn_id from lpn
                 where  lpn_facility_status > '15'
                 and    lpn_facility_status < '90'
                 and    inbound_outbound_indicator = 'O' ) 
        and    item_id in
               ( select item_id from item_cbo where catch_weight_item = '1' ) 
        and    not exists
               ( select 1 from lpn_catch_weight lwc
                 where  lwc.lpn_detail_id = ld.lpn_detail_id );

begin
    for detail in details 
    loop
        select sum(ld.ref_num4*td.qty_pulld) into v_total_weight 
        from   lpn_detail ld, lpn l, task_dtl td
        where  l.lpn_id = ld.lpn_id
        and    l.tc_lpn_id=td.cntr_nbr
        and    ld.item_id=td.item_id
        and    l.lpn_id in
               ( select lpn_id from lpn where tc_lpn_id in
                        ( select cntr_nbr from task_dtl
                          where  carton_nbr in
                                 ( select tc_lpn_id from lpn
                                   where  lpn_id=detail.v_olpn_id ) ) )
        and    ld.ref_num4 is not null
        and    td.invn_need_type = 60
        group by ld.item_id;
    end loop;
```

Comment: Please **SHOW US** the code!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please re-read the FAQ, [edit] your question and add the PL/SQL code that turns your question into a [MCVE].

Comment: provide the query that you have tried and the sample data and outcome.

Comment: Please check the query

Comment: It seems your outer cursor is only producing one row, and the inner cursor is not finding any rows for that `lpn_id`. This is an issue with your data, which we don't have.

Comment: I'm a SQL Server programmer, so forgive what may be an ignorant question, but does Oracle not have an equivalent to `Sum()` and `Group By`?

Comment: No man @WilliamRobertson. Cursor is having 38 records. And i want for loop to pick up one record each team and calculate the sum for each lpn_id.

Comment: How do you know? Have you stepped through it using the debugger?

Comment: Bcz if i run cursor query independently , then its giving me 38 records. After that take any lpn_id and put it in the for-loop query, that query is giving me total sum.But the actual problem is there are around 34 query for which the sum comes as nothing. Only 4 lpn_id are having some SUM.

Answer (score 0):

it may be help you to solve your problem....

```
DECLARE
CURSOR CUR_DAILY_UPDATE IS

select id, amount,status from trxn; 

REC_LON_UP CUR_DAILY_UPDATE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
OPEN CUR_DAILY_UPDATE;
  LOOP
    FETCH CUR_DAILY_UPDATE INTO REC_LON_UP;
    EXIT WHEN CUR_DAILY_UPDATE%NOTFOUND;

        UPDATE trxn_dup FINAL_TAB
        SET FINAL_TAB.amount = REC_LON_UP.amount
        ,FINAL_TAB.status = REC_LON_UP.status
        WHERE FINAL_TAB.id = REC_LON_UP.id;   

  END LOOP;  
  COMMIT;
CLOSE CUR_DAILY_UPDATE;
END;
```

this block code work well in oracle 11g

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, code that is currently posted won't *work well* in Oracle 11g. Actually, it won't work well in any version. Shouldn't `id` on the right side of the `WHERE FINAL_TAB.id = id;` clause be prefixed with cursor variable name? Also, a cursor FOR loop is quite simpler to write & maintain. Moreover, why using PL/SQL? An ordinary `update` would do the same job. Finally, how is this related to OP's question?